# Swiping conflict on viewflippers

Tags: android

I'm using three viewflippers in my activity, each one is loading pictures from server. The three of them are animated and working well. The point is I'm also trying to swipe each one them. I implemented a gesture detector, here is the code:

```
package com.erc.AndroidViewFlipper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class AndroidViewFlipperActivity extends Activity {

    ViewFlipper page,page2;

    Animation animFlipInForeward;
    Animation animFlipOutForeward;
    Animation animFlipInBackward;
    Animation animFlipOutBackward;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        page = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);
        page2 = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper2);

        animFlipInForeward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flipin);
        animFlipOutForeward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flipout);
        animFlipInBackward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flipin_reverse);
        animFlipOutBackward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flipout_reverse);

        page.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.flipin));
        page.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flipout));
        page.startFlipping();
        page.setAutoStart(true);

        page2.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.flipin));
        page2.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flipout));
        page2.startFlipping();
        page2.setAutoStart(true);



    }

    private void SwipeRight(){
        page.setInAnimation(animFlipInBackward);
        page.setOutAnimation(animFlipOutBackward);
        page.showPrevious();
    }

    private void SwipeLeft(){
        page.setInAnimation(animFlipInForeward);
        page.setOutAnimation(animFlipOutForeward);
        page.showNext();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener 
    = new SimpleOnGestureListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {

            float sensitvity = 50;
            if((e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > sensitvity){
                SwipeLeft();
            }else if((e2.getX() - e1.getX()) > sensitvity){
                SwipeRight();
            }

            return true;
        }

    };

    GestureDetector gestureDetector
    = new GestureDetector(simpleOnGestureListener);
}
```

The problem is wherever I touch the screen, the first viewflipper will swipe. What I want is that when I touch a specific viewflipper, only the touched one will swipe. Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

You have mistakenly assigned the same `ViewFlipper` instance to the `page` and `page2` variables. In the following code snippet, both statements use the same view ID, `R.id.flipper`:

```
    page = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);
    page2 = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);
```

[UPDATE]

Also, you need to update your `SwipeRight()`, `SwipeLeft()`, and `simpleOnGestureListener`, as follows (with some added methods as well). The code now tests if a fling gesture started in a `ViewFlipper`, and then swipes that flipper.

```
private void SwipeRight(ViewFlipper vf) { 
    vf.setInAnimation(animFlipInBackward);
    vf.setOutAnimation(animFlipOutBackward);
    vf.showPrevious();
} 

private void SwipeLeft(ViewFlipper vf) { 
    vf.setInAnimation(animFlipInForeward);
    vf.setOutAnimation(animFlipOutForeward);
    vf.showNext();
}

SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener() { 

    @Override 
    public boolean onFling(
            MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) { 

        ViewFlipper vf = getTouchedViewFlipper(e1);
        if (vf == null) {
            return true;
        }

        float sensitivity = 50.0; 
        if ((e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > sensitivity) { 
            SwipeLeft(vf); 
        } else if ((e2.getX() - e1.getX()) > sensitivity) { 
            SwipeRight(vf); 
        } 

        return true; 
    } 

};

private ViewFlipper getTouchedViewFlipper(MotionEvent ev) {
    ViewFlipper vf = checkTouchedViewFlipper(page, ev);
    if (vf == null) {
      vf = checkTouchedViewFlipper(page2, ev);
    }
    return vf;
}

private ViewFlipper checkTouchedViewFlipper(ViewFlipper vf, MotionEvent ev) {
    Rect vfRect;
    vf.getHitRect(vfRect);
    return (vfRect.contains((int)ev.getX(), (int)ev.getY())) ? vf : null;
}
```

Comment: I've edited my answer but that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, I've updated my code and the only thing I changed in your answer is that I initialized the vfRect (Rect vfRect=null) in the method checkTouchedViewFlipper. I'm still unable to swipe each viewflipper